# How can I get Google Chrome to place cursor in this textarea element on page load?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have a simple html page and when I load it in Google chrome I want the cursor to go into the single textarea.  This isn't working -- here's what I have

```
<html>
    <body OnLoad="document.box.focus()">
        <textarea name="box" rows="2000" cols="80">
        </textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

And it seems it can't figure out what element I'm talking about:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'focus' of undefined
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `id` and `getElementById`:

```
<html>
    <body OnLoad="document.getElementById('theTextBox').focus()">
        <textarea id="theTextBox" name="box" rows="2000" cols="80">
        </textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

Chrome doesn't clutter the global namespace with `name` values (and the global namespace is on `window` rather than `document`).

Technically, you *can* do this:

```
<html>
    <body OnLoad="window.theTextBox.focus()">
        <textarea id="theTextBox" name="box" rows="2000" cols="80">
        </textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

...because `id`s get dumped into the global namespace (it's even being specified by the W3C that way, sadly). But you can get collisions in that namespace (for instance, if you had a `var theTextBox;`), whereas `getElementById` is meant to work directly with `id` values.

Answer (score 0):

You get that error message because you can't access a DOM element by name as a property of the `document` object. You should be using [document.getElementsByName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName) to access an array of all the elements sharing a given name (in your simple case you'd use `document.getElementsByName('box')[0].focus()` to access the single `textarea`).

Alternatively and preferably you should set some ID on that element (like `<textarea id="box" rows="2000" cols="80" ...>`) and then access the element using [document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById) so that you always get precisely one element.